# What replaces /etc/services in openSUSE, and how

Tags: opensuse, services, postfix, etc, fetchmail

I am running openSUSE Linux, the Tumbleweed version. I discovered that it does
not use an /etc/services file, though I do not know what is replacing it, or
how it is done, and I do not have much success searching the web.

Actually, what happened to me is that my mail system stopped working correctly
after a major system update, both in-mail and out-mail. After much testing and
debugging with a more expert user (of other Linux distros), we
discovered that the /etc/services file was missing.

Thinking it had been accidentally destroyed, we created a small one to provide
at least for the ports used for email. And it did solve my mail problems.

To do things cleanly, I asked another openSUSE Tumbleweed user for his copy of
the file as provided in the distribution. But he did not find it in his own
system, which has no mail problem. So, it is not necessary.

Apparently, I had solved my problem by accident.

Could someone at least confirm that /etc/services is no longer normally used
in this openSUSE Linux. But I would like an explanation of how things are now
done, and if possible of why my problem was solved by adding /etc/services,
and whether I could solve it without /etc/services.

(reported to the best of my understanding and memory of events)

Comment: Last thing I've heard that `/etc` is moving to `/usr/etc` so a lot things break because of some dependencies/configuration that cannot be done through the update.

Comment: Though incomplete, your comment is worth an answer imho. I just checked on my system, and I do have a very complete services file `/usr/etc/services`. It is dated from Jan 30, about a week before my last update. It is clear that forgetting the change in some parts of the code (involving in my case `smtp`, `pop2` and `pop3`) could lead to the behavior I observed. Still, this is so critical that I am surprised I did not find any reference to similar bugs when searching the web. Then, it is also true that Tumbleweed is bleeding edge, which is always a bit risky.

Comment: I gave you the info that I have, if it is incomplete then I can't give you anymore answer since I'm not a weed user. Also are you not subscribed in the mailing list for tumbleweed? You should so because tumbleweed is a `rolling release` not like the stable leap....

Comment: I suggested you change your comment into an answer not as a request for more
information, but because I wanted to thank you by voting you up. I am not yet
registered with tumbleweed mailing list because I am a fairly new user
recently converted to this distro by a friend. Actually my first reaction was
to register with SUSE. But for some reason I got into a registration mess
involving the site `microfocus.com` (no idea what they do) and apparently some
local paranoia (possibly justified). So I also asked on SE which I am more
familiar with.

Comment: Here is the lists of mailinglist.  https://lists.opensuse.org/   and the factory mailing list. which you need to subscribe,  `https://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-factory/`

Comment: Your information was a good answer.  I used it to search the web and found several references, explaining the problem, including `https://www.reddit.com/r/tumbleweed/comments/eytxif/psa_20200201_etcservices_moved_to_usretcservices/` and `https://kubic.opensuse.org/blog/2019-12-05-usr-etc/`, I just searched for `usr/etc/services`.

Answer (score 5):

Since [Jetchisel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/99037/jetchisel) will not turn his comment into an answer, I am doing it here,
with more details.

Warning: I am not an expert on these issues and this is only to make available
whatever understanding I gathered, painfully, as I did not have the right
keywords for searching.

As commented by Jetchisel, it seems that in some distros configuration files
usually found in folder `/etc` is being reorganized into two folders `/etc` and
`/usr/etc`. As I understand it, the purpose is to separate configurations that
are being maintained at distro level and configurations maintained by the
superuser, so as to minimize conflicts when an installed system is updated.

With a single folder, such conflict are harder to resolve automatically, and
updating software may leave the system with two versions of the configuration
file `foo.conf`, which can be the old version used before update together with
`foo.conf.rpmnew` proposed by the update, or alternatively the old version is
renamed `foo.conf.rpmsave` and the name `foo.conf` is used for the configuration
file proposed by the update. The idea is that the superuser with merge the two
files in the most appropriate way.  See `rpmnew` and `rpmsave` on yout favorite
search engine.

However, one still need to arbitrate between configuration files, and this is
done by the configuration file `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. My problem was that The
distro was updated so that `/etc/services` became `/usr/etc/services`.  And the
change was reflected in `/etc/nsswitch.conf.rpmnew`, but it was not active, as
long as I did not merge it with my old version `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (but I did
not know).

Apparently, if you touch configuration files, it is always wise to check for
the appearance of suffixes like `.rpmsave` or `.rpmnew` after an update. I am not
sure which are the concerned distros.  I am using openSUSE Tumbleweed, and otherwise rather happy with it.

References I started from:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/tumbleweed/comments/eytxif/psa_20200201_etcservices_moved_to_usretcservices/
- https://kubic.opensuse.org/blog/2019-12-05-usr-etc/

Comment: nscd still searching for /etc/services nscd[738]: 738 checking for monitored file `/etc/services': No such file or directory